Automatic detection of FFT peaks in image: Python
I have this image, and I want to suppress the peaks in this image, which represnts the scratches in the original image (but that is besides the point). All I want, is to make an algorithm that Automatically Identifies the peaks in the Image and then suppress them (make it 0).
This is the code I wrote through which I have received the given result. You can look at the libraries, and I have code it in Python.
What I want?
I want the algorithm to be in Python, which automatically detects the FFT peaks (co-ordinates) and then supress them. If anyone knows, How to achieve this, your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Please advise which are the peaks that you want. Mark them in a copy of the picture.

I have added the image. and also comments on the picture. If you want the original picture, I can add that too.

context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79132561/remove-scratches-using-python

original image to help us get reproducible results? @coldaf_876

@coldaf_876 Thanks for the commented image, but are you looking to remove the just the high frequency lines or all lines, even the long diagonal, horizontal and vertical one that are close to the central point or only the short ones at higher frequencies?  Where do the dark rings come from?

@coldaf_876 Why is there a red circle graphic on the image? Won't that affect your FFT spectrum image?

@fmw42 It can but the circle is not important. If you suppress it, it is fine.

@coldaf_876 what is X--solution-->Y? If you want to remove scratches (Y = X - scratches), a simple Gaussian blur might solve your problem, there's really no need for FFT in this case. + as mentioned by fmw, the annotations in your images should not be there.

@TinoD Can you provide the code for that? I want to see the results. Thanks.

@coldaf_876 am not near my computer, check out some of the filters in scipy.ndimage

@coldaf_876 Please remove the circle from your input image. You should have the original already without the graphic red circle. That will affect your FFT spectrum image. It is possible to remove the bright lines if you know where to look and know which ones they are. I have a notch filter script on my web site. But it is a bash shell script running Imagemagick. It tries to remove the bright spots and certain lines. But probably will not work with your image.

`@coldaf_876 You have a blue overlay on that one. Can you not provide and good image with no overlay graphic and with obvious scratches.  FFT notch filtering is not a good approach to something that does not have repeatative features at uniform intervals.

@fmw42 did the new image worked?

Hey, @coldaf_876 did you try it with the good image you pasted? I have a feeling these peaks and valleys that you are getting in the FFT are due to the annotations. Again, I don't believe you need to apply any frequency filtering at all. A simple gaussian bluring is enough to remove scratches

@TinoD can you provide a sample code for the 'A simple gaussian bluring is enough to remove scratches'? It would be helpful.

Here you go @coldaf_876: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html Have fun reading and understanding

@TinoD 2 things I noticed: 1) gaussian blurring blurs the image, I don't want that. I have further evaluation to do on the image. If you will see the FFT notation image at the beginning of the question, you will see what I am trying to do.
2) I am doing FFT because it specifically suppresses the given scratches, without blurring the output.

Frequency filtering will affect the whole image as well, not just the scratches. Am not sure what your desired result should look like, and I think you don't either. Again I would like to point out that the FFT image in your question is far off from the actual FFT that you get when using the original image without the annotation. I suggest you post this question on signal processing and ask for advice there.

@coldaf_876 Yes, I got the image, but was too busy to work on it yesterday.  But from examination, I doubt FFT processing will help. In order to remove features, they have to be repetitive at equal intervals. You do not have that as far as I can see.  Your scratches are random looking! But if those were removed, what is there left? It looks like the only features in the image are the scratches and a flat looking background. What are you trying to bring out in your image after the scratches are removed? Have you tried manually painting over the features in the FFT to see what the result is?

@coldaf_876 I do not see any "worm-like structures" in your image. I know of no other method to remove random scratches that are that dense. Individual scratches could be removed by inpainting for example.

you guys are 28 comments into trying to figure out what OP means. I think it's time to call it quits and vote it as requiring details or clarity. or maybe open up the chat, to accelerate this back and forth.

@Christoph Rackwitz I would have gone to chat, but never got a link to do so and I do not see any button or link for that.  How does one force going to chat?

@coldaf_876 As I have said, I do not know any method to effectively remove all you massive amounts of scratches. FFT won't help as far as I know as your scratches are not random. So notch filtering probably will not work. I think you need to look elsewhere than this forum. Probably time to quit this discussion.

there's no chat link here at the moment. regardless of that, you can always start a chat by going through the burger menu (top right) and creating it: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new

Do not be alarmed by the garbled noisy image in the other answer. That is due to Imagemagick.
FFT processing really won't help. It may erase some of the directional scratches but what good is that gonna do? Right, not much. And it will introduce other artefacts. My recommendation: forget about FFT.
Input:

Spectrum with blanked-out areas (visualization, not the true data):

After correct inverse FFT:


Hey, Thank you for the reply. Can you add the code to get this output (After correct inverse FFT)? I want to check something.

I didn't use code for this, I used a program called "ImageJ". the code would involve fft (either from numpy or opencv), zeroing out certain ranges in the spectrum, and then inverse fft. and minding the scaling of values. both numpy and opencv's fft/ifft (or dft) functions have flags to control the scaling.

is it possible to achieve this in Python?

well yes that looks correct. next you should try the inverse fft on that spectrum. you should be getting the original image back, except it's now floating point and maybe the values are scaled weirdly. you should use the "real-valued" fft/dft and inverse functions here, or else take the real parts of the resulting complex-valued image (not the spectrum)

So I should put one horizontal line at the center (avoiding the center point to suppress the high frequencies) and then do the ifft as you told, right? that should be enough to get the result you have given as "After correct inverse FFT".

I assure you, the same result can be obtained with code. there is no need to remove that demonstration from (only) my answer. the other answer didn't use code either. imagemagick is a tool just like ImageJ.

Yes I trust you brother. I have removed it because of the images. Don't worry. I have recreated the results and also thank you very much once again for all the guidance. The same reason I have 'Accepted' your answer.

Just to show you that FFT processing won't help you, I processed your image. Without the graphic overlays, there are not any significant features in the FFT spectrum.
Input:

Spectrum (log of magnitude):

I manually drew black lines over the horizontal bright area avoiding the center.

Then I reversed the process using the blackened image and the phase image.

For simplicity and efficiency of commands, I used Imagemagick to do the processing.
The colored noise is due to Imagemagick processing all 3 channels of the input image. I did not convert to grayscale.

That's what I was tring to say as well, the "ring" and "line" artifacts seen in the question are not due to scratches, but to the annotation in the original image. Hence the idea of peaks detection in FFT was not really based on the results from the actual image

@Tino D That is why I insisted on getting an image without the graphic overlays. Guess we were both on the same path to that.

the imagemagick noise is not due to color processing. it might be some per-channel thresholding, or it didn't account for the scaling that a FFT roundtrip requires, and just clipped the values.

There is no per channel thresholding in the processing.
